# Div border affected after removing display:table and table-cell

Tags: html, css, border

Im having an issue with a border on my outer div. (all)
I just had to remove `display: table;` from html and `display: table-cell;` from `.all` to solve an issue i was having. It turns out that they were keeping the border in check on `.all`.
Ive been able to replicate it the best i can in a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/99e7cz8d/

In my actual site the border is doing the same thing on the top right corner as it is on the top left, in the fiddle only the left corner is doing it.

I need the border of `.all` to show up on all sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `overflow:hidden` on `.all` - http://jsfiddle.net/99e7cz8d/10/

```
.all {
    /*display: table-cell;*/
    border: 2px solid #006699;
    background-color: #0F3053;
    overflow:hidden
}
```